# Book recommendation: protocols and recipes handbook for molecular biology / biochemistry

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, lab-techniques, book-recommendation

I'm a 5th-year PhD student in chemical biology. I've mostly been doing computational work, so my bench skills are rusty. To help me, I'd like a handbook of common techniques -- transformations, ELISA, protein purification, DNA extraction, SDS-PAGE, column chromatography, etc. I'd especially like a collection of recipes for buffers, etc.

I can find some protocols, but it's hard to find ones covering the more basic methods, and I'd like something cohesive. And there's something satisfying about an actual book.

I found these (and browsed through them in an HHMI library once):

- [https://www.amazon.com/Kathy-Barker/dp/0879697083/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0879697083)
- [https://www.amazon.com/Lab-Ref-Handbook-Reagents-Reference/dp/1936113791/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1936113791)

But they're pretty out of date! Most of the techniques are still valid, but I know many have been superseded. There are still a lot of radioligand assays (which are now uncommon in most labs).

So, can anyone recommend a book that could help someone relearn basic techniques?

---

My experience is that techniques are almost most often taught by hands-on, one-on-one training -- you find someone who knows the technique and ask them to show you, but COVID-19 distancing protocols make that nearly impossible. (The good news is that I often have the lab to myself and an underused supply of chemical stocks and reagents.)

Comment: Not a book recommendation but you should check out : https://www.protocols.io/ As someone with a computational background, I'm not the happiest about the about the way they write the protocols but they are definitely legit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extremely old-school answer here would be Maniatis' [Molecular Cloning](http://www.molecularcloning.com/). They put out a new edition every decade or so, there is one from 2012 that is updated.

To get an idea of the book's impact in molecular biology, see this review from their website:

> “In every kitchen there is at least one indispensable cookbook...Molecular Cloning: A Laboratory Manual fills the same niche in the laboratory (with) information to help both the inexperienced and the advanced user. (It) has once again established its primacy as the molecular laboratory manual and is likely to be found on lab benches...around the world.” ——Trends in Neurosciences

Likely there are more streamlined books out there at this point (this book runs at 3 volumes), but it's hard to see how to dispense with Maniatis.

It includes recipes for buffers etc. (see end of listing below). It is a little lighter on protein techniques, though, so I don't think you will find e.g. ELISA in there, though you will definitely find SDS-PAGE.

Here is a current chapter/protocol heading (you can scroll through the monospaced text). I had to delete a bunch of subheadings to make it fit under 30K characters:

```
Volume 1
Chapter 1: Isolation and Quantification of DNA1
Protocol 1: Preparation of Plasmid DNA by Alkaline Lysis with SDS: Minipreps
Protocol 2: Preparation of Plasmid DNA by Alkaline Lysis with SDS: Maxipreps
Protocol 3: Isolating DNA from Gram-Negative Bacteria (e.g., E. coli)
Protocol 4: Precipitation of DNA with Ethanol
Protocol 5: Precipitation of DNA with Isopropanol
Protocol 6: Concentrating and Desalting Nucleic Acids with Microconcentrators
Protocol 7: Concentrating Nucleic Acids by Extraction with Butanol
Protocol 8: Preparation of Single-Stranded Bacteriophage M13 DNA by Precipitation with Polyethylene Glycol
Protocol 9: Plating Bacteriophage M13
Protocol 10: Growing Bacteriophage M13 in Liquid Culture
Protocol 11: Preparation of Double-Stranded (Replicative Form) Bacteriophage M13 DNA
Protocol 12: Isolation of High-Molecular-Weight DNA Using Organic Solvents to Purify DNA
Protocol 13: Isolation of High-Molecular-Weight DNA from Mammalian Cells Using Proteinase K and Phenol
Protocol 14: A Single-Step Method for the Simultaneous Preparation of DNA, RNA, and Protein from Cells and Tissues
Protocol 15: Preparation of Genomic DNA from Mouse Tails and Other Small Samples
Protocol 16: Rapid Isolation of Yeast DNA
Protocol 17: Using Ethidium Bromide to Estimate the Amount of DNA in Bands after Electrophoresis through Minigels
Protocol 18: Estimating the Concentration of DNA by Fluorometry Using Hoechst 33258
Protocol 19: Quantifying DNA in Solution with PicoGreen
Chapter 2: Analysis of DNA81
Protocol 1: Agarose Gel Electrophoresis
Protocol 2: Detection of DNA in Agarose Gels by Staining
Protocol 3: Polyacrylamide Gel Electrophoresis
Protocol 4: Detection of DNA in Polyacrylamide Gels by Staining
Protocol 5: Detection of DNA in Polyacrylamide Gels by Autoradiography
Protocol 6: Alkaline Agarose Gel Electrophoresis
Protocol 7: Imaging: Autoradiography and Phosphorimaging
Protocol 8: Recovery of DNA from Agarose Gels Using Glass Beads
Protocol 9: Recovery of DNA from Low-Melting-Temperature Agarose Gels: Organic Extraction
Protocol 10: Isolation of DNA Fragments from Polyacrylamide Gels by the Crush and Soak Method
Protocol 11: Southern Blotting
Protocol 12: Southern Blotting: Simultaneous Transfer of DNA from an Agarose Gel to Two Membranes
Protocol 13: Southern Hybridization of Radiolabeled Probes to Nucleic Acids Immobilized on Membranes
Chapter 3: Cloning and Transformation with Plasmid Vectors157
Protocol 1: The Hanahan Method for Preparation and Transformation of Competent E. coli: High-Efficiency Transformation
Protocol 2: The Inoue Method for Preparation and Transformation of Competent E. coli: Ultracompetent Cells
Protocol 3: Easy Transformation of E. coli: Nanoparticle-Mediated Transformation
Protocol 4: Transformation of E. coli by Electroporation
Protocol 5: Cloning in Plasmid Vectors: Directional Cloning
Protocol 6: Cloning in Plasmid Vectors: Blunt-End Cloning
Protocol 7: Dephosphorylation of Plasmid DNA
Protocol 8: Attaching Phosphorylated Adaptors/Linkers to Blunt-Ended DNAs
Protocol 9: Cloning PCR Products: Addition of Restriction Sites to the Termini of Amplified DNA
Protocol 10: Cloning PCR Products: Blunt-End Cloning
Protocol 11: Cloning PCR Products: Making T Vectors
Protocol 12: Cloning PCR Products: TA Cloning
Protocol 13: Cloning PCR Products: TOPO TA Cloning
Protocol 14: Screening Bacterial Colonies Using X-Gal and IPTG: -Complementation

Chapter 4: Gateway Recombinational Cloning261
Protocol 1: Propagating Gateway Vectors
Protocol 2: Generating an ORF Entry Clone and Destination Clone
Protocol 3: Using Multisite LR Cloning to Generate a Destination Clone
Panel: Gateway Recombinational Cloning261
Panel: Basic Principles and Applications of Gateway Cloning262
Panel: Disadvantages of Gateway Cloning and Alternative Cloning Systems264
Panel: Generating Gateway-Compatible Vectors280
Chapter 5: Working with Bacterial Artificial Chromosomes and Other High-Capacity Vectors281
Protocol 1: Small-Scale Isolation of BAC DNA and Verification by PCR
Protocol 2: Large-Scale Preparation and Linearization of BAC DNA
Protocol 3: Examination of BAC DNA Quality and Quantity by Pulsed-Field Gel Electrophoresis
Protocol 4: Two-Step BAC Engineering: Preparation of Shuttle Vector DNA
Protocol 5: Preparation of the A Homology Arm (A-Box) and B Homology Arm (B-Box)
Protocol 6: Cloning of the A and B Homology Arms into the Shuttle Vector
Protocol 7: Preparation and Verification of the Recombinant Shuttle Vector
Protocol 8: Electroporation of Competent BAC Host Cells with the Recombinant Shuttle Vector
Protocol 9: Verification of Cointegrates and Selection of Resolved BAC Clones
Protocol 10: One-Step BAC Modification: Preparation of Plasmids
Protocol 11: Preparation of the A Homology Arm (A-Box)
Protocol 12: Cloning of the A Homology Arm into Reporter-Shuttle Vector
Protocol 13: Transformation of the BAC Host with the RecA Vector
Protocol 14: Transfer of the Reporter Vector into BAC/RecA Cells and Selection of Cointegrates
Protocol 15: Growth of S. cerevisiae and Preparation of DNA
Protocol 16: Small-Scale Preparations of Yeast DNA

Chapter 6: Extraction, Purification, and Analysis of RNA from Eukaryotic Cells345
Protocol 1: Purification of Total RNA from Mammalian Cells and Tissues
Protocol 2: Isolation of Total RNA from Zebrafish Embryos and Adults
Protocol 3: Total RNA Isolation from Drosophila melanogaster
Protocol 4: Total RNA Extraction from Caenorhabditis elegans
Protocol 5: Total RNA Extraction from Saccharomyces cerevisiae Using Hot Acid Phenol
Protocol 6: Quantifying and Storing RNA
Protocol 7: Precipitation of RNA with Ethanol
Protocol 8: Removing DNA Contamination from RNA Samples by Treatment with RNase-Free DNase I
Protocol 9: Isolation of Poly(A) Messenger RNA Using Magnetic Oligo(dT) Beads
Protocol 10: Separation of RNA according to Size: Electrophoresis of RNA through Agarose Gels Containing Formaldehyde
Protocol 11: Separation of RNA according to Size: Electrophoresis of RNA through Denaturing Urea Polyacrylamide Gels
Protocol 12: Transfer and Fixation of Denatured RNA in Agarose Gels to Membranes
Protocol 13: Transfer and Fixation of Denatured RNA in Polyacrylamide Gels to Membranes by Electrophoretic Transfer
Protocol 14: Northern Hybridization
Protocol 15: Dot and Slot Hybridization of Purified RNA
Protocol 16: Mapping RNA with Nuclease S1
Protocol 17: Ribonuclease Protection: Mapping RNA with Ribonuclease and Radiolabeled RNA Probes
Protocol 18: Analysis of RNA by Primer Extension


Chapter 7: Polymerase Chain Reaction455
Protocol 1: The Basic Polymerase Chain Reaction
Protocol 2: Hot Start PCR
Protocol 3: Touchdown PCR
Protocol 4: PCR Amplification of GC-Rich Templates
Protocol 5: Long and Accurate PCR (LA PCR)
Protocol 6: Inverse PCR
Protocol 7: Nested PCR
Protocol 8: Amplification of cDNA Generated by Reverse Transcription of mRNA: Two-Step RT-PCR
Protocol 9: Rapid Amplification of Sequences from the 5 Ends of mRNAs: 5-RACE
Protocol 10: Rapid Amplification of Sequences from the 3 Ends of mRNAs: 3-RACE
Protocol 11: Screening Colonies by PCR


Chapter 8: Bioinformatics541
Protocol 1: Visualizing Genomic Annotations with the UCSC Genome Browser
Protocol 2: Sequence Alignment and Homology Search with BLAST and ClustalW
Protocol 3: Designing PCR Primers Using Primer3Plus
Protocol 4: Expression Profiling by Microarray and RNA-seq
Protocol 5: Mapping Billions of Short Reads to a Reference Genome
Protocol 6: Identifying Regions Enriched in a ChIP-seq Data Set (Peak Finding)
Protocol 7: Discovering cis-Regulatory Motifs


Volume 2
Chapter 9: Quantification of DNA and RNA by Real-Time Polymerase Chain Reaction631
Protocol 1: Optimizing Primer and Probe Concentrations for Use in Real-Time PCR
Protocol 2: Constructing a Standard Curve
Protocol 3: Quantification of DNA by Real-Time PCR
Protocol 4: Quantification of RNA by Real-Time RT-PCR
Protocol 5: Analysis and Normalization of Real-Time PCR Experimental Data


Chapter 10: Nucleic Acid Platform Technologies683
Protocol 1: Printing Microarrays
Protocol 2: Round A/Round B Amplification of DNA
Protocol 3: T7 Linear Amplification of DNA (TLAD) for Nucleosomal and Other DNA < 500 bp
Protocol 4: Amplification of RNA
Protocol 5: Direct Cyanine-dUTP Labeling of RNA
Protocol 6: Indirect Aminoallyl-dUTP Labeling of RNA
Protocol 7: Cyanine-dCTP Labeling of DNA Using Klenow
Protocol 8: Indirect Labeling of DNA
Protocol 9: Blocking Polylysines on Homemade Microarrays
Protocol 10: Hybridization to Homemade Microarrays


Chapter 11: DNA Sequencing735
Protocol 1: Preparing Plasmid Subclones for Capillary Sequencing
Protocol 2: Preparing PCR Products for Capillary Sequencing
Protocol 3: Cycle-Sequencing Reactions
Protocol 4: Whole Genome: Manual Library Preparation
Protocol 5: Whole Genome: Automated, Nonindexed Library Preparation
Protocol 6: Whole Genome: Automated, Indexed Library Preparation
Protocol 7: Preparation of a 3-kb Mate-Pair Library for Illumina Sequencing
Protocol 8: Preparation of an 8-kb Mate-Pair Library for Illumina Sequencing
Protocol 9: RNA-Seq: RNA Conversion to cDNA and Amplification
Protocol 10: Solution-Phase Exome Capture
Protocol 11: Automated Size Selection
Protocol 12: Library Quantification Using SYBR Green-qPCR
Protocol 13: Library Quantification Using PicoGreen Fluorometry
Protocol 14: Library Quantification: Fluorometric Quantitation of Double-Stranded or Single-Stranded DNA Samples Using the Qubit System
Protocol 15: Preparation of Small-Fragment Libraries for 454 Sequencing
Protocol 16: sstDNA Library Capture and emPCR
Protocol 17: Roche/454 Sequencer: Executing a Sequencing Run
Protocol 18: Validation
Protocol 19: Quality Assessment of Sequence Data
Protocol 20: Data Analysis

Chapter 12: Analysis of DNA Methylation in Mammalian Cells893
Protocol 1: DNA Bisulfite Sequencing for Single-Nucleotide-Resolution DNA Methylation Detection
Protocol 2: Methylation-Specific PCR for Gene-Specific DNA Methylation Detection
Protocol 3: Methyl-Cytosine-Based Immunoprecipitation for DNA Methylation Analysis
Protocol 4: High-Throughput Deep Sequencing for Mapping Mammalian DNA Methylation
Protocol 5: Roche 454 Clonal Sequencing of Bisulfite-Converted DNA Libraries
Protocol 6: Illumina Sequencing of Bisulfite-Converted DNA Libraries

Chapter 13: Preparation of Labeled DNA, RNA, and Oligonucleotide Probes943
Protocol 1: Random Priming: Labeling of Purified DNA Fragments by Extension of Random Oligonucleotides
Protocol 2: Random Priming: Labeling of DNA by Extension of Random Oligonucleotides in the Presence of Melted Agarose
Protocol 3: Labeling of DNA Probes by Nick Translation
Protocol 4: Labeling of DNA Probes by Polymerase Chain Reaction
Protocol 5: Synthesis of Single-Stranded RNA Probes by In Vitro Transcription
Protocol 6: Synthesis of cDNA Probes from mRNA Using Random Oligonucleotide Primers
Protocol 7: Radiolabeling of Subtracted cDNA Probes by Random Oligonucleotide Extension
Protocol 8: Labeling 3 Termini of Double-Stranded DNA Using the Klenow Fragment of E. coli DNA Polymerase I
Protocol 9: Dephosphorylation of DNA Fragments with Alkaline Phosphatase
Protocol 10: Phosphorylation of DNA Molecules with Protruding 5-Hydroxyl Termini
Protocol 11: Phosphorylation of DNA Molecules with Dephosphorylated Blunt Ends or Recessed 5 Termini
Protocol 12: Phosphorylating the 5 Termini of Oligonucleotides Using T4 Polynucleotide Kinase
Protocol 13: Labeling the 3 Termini of Oligonucleotides Using Terminal Deoxynucleotidyl Transferase
Protocol 14: Labeling of Synthetic Oligonucleotides Using the Klenow Fragment of E. coli DNA Polymerase I
Protocol 15: Purification of Labeled Oligonucleotides by Precipitation with Ethanol
Protocol 16: Purification of Labeled Oligonucleotides by Size-Exclusion Chromatography
Protocol 17: Purification of Labeled Oligonucleotides by Chromatography on a Sep-Pak C18 Column
Protocol 18: Hybridization of Oligonucleotide Probes in Aqueous Solutions: Washing in Buffers Containing Quaternary Ammonium Salts

Chapter 14: Methods for In Vitro Mutagenesis1059
Protocol 1: Random Mutagenesis Using Error-Prone DNA Polymerases
Protocol 2: Creating Insertions or Deletions Using Overlap Extension PCR Mutagenesis
Protocol 3: In Vitro Mutagenesis Using Double-Stranded DNA Templates: Selection of Mutants with DpnI
Protocol 4: Altered -Lactamase Selection Approach for Site-Directed Mutagenesis
Protocol 5: Oligonucleotide-Directed Mutagenesis by Elimination of a Unique Restriction Site (USE Mutagenesis)
Protocol 6: Saturation Mutagenesis by Codon Cassette Insertion
Protocol 7: Random Scanning Mutagenesis
Protocol 8: Multisite-Directed Mutagenesis
Protocol 9: Megaprimer PCR-Based Mutagenesis

Chapter 15: Introducing Genes into Cultured Mammalian Cells1131
Protocol 1: DNA Transfection Mediated by Cationic Lipid Reagents
Protocol 2: Calcium-Phosphate-Mediated Transfection of Eukaryotic Cells with Plasmid DNAs
Protocol 3: Calcium-Phosphate-Mediated Transfection of Cells with High-Molecular-Weight Genomic DNA
Protocol 4: Transfection Mediated by DEAE-Dextran: High-Efficiency Method
Protocol 5: DNA Transfection by Electroporation
Protocol 6: Analysis of Cell Viability by the alamarBlue Assay
Protocol 7: Analysis of Cell Viability by the Lactate Dehydrogenase Assay
Protocol 8: Analysis of Cell Viability by the MTT Assay

Chapter 16: Introducing Genes into Mammalian Cells: Viral Vectors1209
Protocol 1: Construction of Recombinant Adenovirus Genomes by Direct Cloning
Protocol 2: Release of the Cloned Recombinant Adenovirus Genome for Rescue and Expansion
Protocol 3: Purification of the Recombinant Adenovirus by Cesium Chloride Gradient Centrifugation
Protocol 4: Characterization of the Purified Recombinant Adenovirus for Viral Genome Structure by Restriction Enzyme Digestions
Protocol 5: Measuring the Infectious Titer of Recombinant Adenovirus Using TCID50 End-Point Dilution and qPCR
Protocol 6: Detection Assay for Replication-Competent Adenovirus by Concentration Passage and Real-Time qPCR
Protocol 7: Production of rAAVs by Transient Transfection
Protocol 8: Purification of rAAVs by Cesium Chloride Gradient Sedimentation
Protocol 9: Purification of rAAVs by Iodixanol Gradient Centrifugation
Protocol 10: Purification of rAAV2s by Heparin Column Affinity Chromatography
Protocol 11: Enrichment of Fully Packaged Virions in Column-Purified rAAV Preparations by Iodixanol Gradient Centrifugation Followed by Anion-Exchange Column Chromatography
Protocol 12: Titration of rAAV Genome Copy Number Using Real-Time qPCR
Protocol 13: Sensitive Determination of Infectious Titer of rAAVs Using TCID50 End-Point Dilution and qPCR
Protocol 14: Analysis of rAAV Sample Morphology Using Negative Staining and High-Resolution Electron Microscopy
Protocol 15: Analysis of rAAV Purity Using Silver-Stained SDS-PAGE
Protocol 16: Production of High-Titer Retrovirus and Lentivirus Vectors
Protocol 17: Titration of Lentivirus Vectors
Protocol 18: Monitoring Lentivirus Vector Stocks for Replication-Competent Viruses

Volume 3
Chapter 17: Analysis of Gene Regulation Using Reporter Systems1335
Protocol 1: Assay for -Galactosidase in Extracts of Mammalian Cells
Protocol 2: Single Luciferase Reporter Assay
Protocol 3: Dual Luciferase Reporter Assay
Protocol 4: Using ELISA to Measure GFP Production
Protocol 5: Generation of Cell Lines with Tetracycline-Regulated Gene Expression

Chapter 18: RNA Interference and Small RNA Analysis1415
Protocol 1: Preparation of siRNA Duplexes
Protocol 2: RNAi in Mammalian Cells by siRNA Duplex Transfection
Protocol 3: RNAi in Drosophila S2 Cells by siRNA Duplex Transfection
Protocol 4: Preparation of dsRNAs by In Vitro Transcription
Protocol 5: RNAi in Drosophila S2 Cells by dsRNA Soaking
Protocol 6: RNAi in Drosophila S2 Cells by dsRNA Transfection
Protocol 7: Analysis of Small RNAs by Northern Hybridization
Protocol 8: Analysis of Small RNAs by Quantitative Reverse Transcription PCR
Protocol 9: Construction of Small RNA Libraries for High-Throughput Sequencing
Protocol 10: Preparation of Antisense Oligonucleotides to Inhibit miRNA Function
Protocol 11: Inhibiting miRNA Function by Antisense Oligonucleotides in Cultured Mammalian Cells
Protocol 12: Inhibiting miRNA Function by Antisense Oligonucleotides in Drosophila S2 Cells

Chapter 19: Expressing Cloned Genes for Protein Production, Purification, and Analysis1481
Protocol 1: Expression of Cloned Genes in E. coli Using IPTG-Inducible Promoters
Protocol 2: Expression of Cloned Genes Using the Baculovirus Expression System
Protocol 3: Expression of Cloned Genes in P. pastoris Using the Methanol-Inducible Promoter AOX1
Protocol 4: Preparation of Cell Extract for Purification of Soluble Proteins Expressed in E. coli
Protocol 5: Purification of Polyhistidine-Tagged Proteins by Immobilized Metal Affinity Chromatography
Protocol 6: Purification of Fusion Proteins by Affinity Chromatography on Glutathione Resin
Protocol 7: Solubilization of Expressed Proteins from Inclusion Bodies
Protocol 8: SDS-PAGE of Proteins
Protocol 9: Analysis of Proteins by Immunoblotting
Protocol 10: Methods for Measuring the Concentrations of Proteins

Chapter 20: Cross-Linking Technologies for Analysis of Chromatin Structure and Function1637
Protocol 1: Formaldehyde Cross-Linking
Protocol 2: Preparation of Cross-Linked Chromatin for ChIP
Protocol 3: ChIP
Protocol 4: ChIPQuantitative PCR (ChIP-qPCR)
Protocol 5: ChIP-chip
Protocol 6: ChIP-seq
Protocol 7: Generation of 3C Libraries from Cross-Linked Cells
Protocol 8: Generation of ChIP-loop Libraries
Protocol 9: Generation of Control Ligation Product Libraries
Protocol 10: PCR Detection of 3C Ligation Products Present in 3C, ChIP-loop, and Control Libraries: Library Titration and Interaction Frequency Analysis
Protocol 11: 4C Analysis of 3C, ChIP-loop, and Control Libraries
Protocol 12: 5C Analysis of 3C, ChIP-loop, and Control Libraries

Chapter 21: Mapping of In Vivo RNA-Binding Sites by UV-Cross-Linking Immunoprecipitation (CLIP)1703
Protocol 1: Optimization of Immunoprecipitation Stringency for CLIP
Protocol 2: UV Cross-Linking of Live Cells and Lysate Preparation
Protocol 3: RNase Titration, Immunoprecipitation, and SDS-PAGE
Protocol 4: 3-Linker Ligation and Size Selection by SDS-PAGE
Protocol 5: Isolation of the RNA Tags, 5-Linker Ligation, and Reverse Transcription PCR Amplification
Protocol 6: Sequencing of RNA CLIP Tags
Protocol 7: Gel Purification and Storage of RNA Linkers

Chapter 22: Gateway-Compatible Yeast One-Hybrid and Two-Hybrid Assays1761
Protocol 1: Generating Yeast One-Hybrid DNA-Bait Strains
Protocol 2: Generating Yeast Two-Hybrid Bait Strains
Protocol 3: Identifying Interactors from an Activation Domain Prey Library
Protocol 4: High-Efficiency Yeast Transformation
Protocol 5: Colony Lift Colorimetric Assay for -Galactosidase Activity
Protocol 6: Yeast Colony PCR


Panel: Reagents and Buffers1811
Panel: Tris Buffers1828
Panel: Good Buffers1829
Panel: Phosphate Buffers (Gomori Buffers)1830
Panel: Phenol1834
Panel: Equilibration of Phenol1834
Panel: Phenol:Chloroform:Isoamyl Alcohol (25:24:1)1834
Panel: Deionization of Formamide1834
Panel: Blocking Agents Used for Nucleic Acid Hybridization1836
Panel: Blocking Agents Used for Western Blotting1836
Panel: Commonly Used Techniques1843
Panel: Siliconizing Glassware, Plasticware, and Glass Wool1843
Panel: Preparation of RNase-Free Glassware1844
Panel: Hemocytometry Counting1846
Panel: Viability Staining1847
Panel: Precipitation of Nucleic Acids with Trichloroacetic Acid1849
Panel: Removing Ethidium Bromide from DNA1851
Panel: Disposing of Ethidium Bromide1851
Panel: Decontamination of Concentrated Solutions of Ethidium Bromide (Solutions Containing >0.5 mg/mL)1851
Panel: Decontamination of Dilute Solutions of Ethidium Bromide (e.g., Electrophoresis Buffer Containing 0.5 g/mL Ethidium Bromide)1852
Panel: Commercial Decontamination Kits1852
Panel: Detection Systems1855
Panel: Ethidium Bromide1855
Panel: Methylene Blue1857
Panel: SYBR Dyes1857
Panel: Chemiluminescent Labels1860
Panel: Chemiluminescent Enzyme Assays1861
Panel: Commercial Reagents, Kits, and Luminometers1863
Panel: Horseradish Peroxidase1865
Panel: Digoxygenin1869
Panel: BCIP1873
Panel: AMPPD1876
Panel: Immunoglobulin-Binding Proteins: Proteins A, G, and L1879
Panel: General Safety and Hazardous Material1885
```

Comment: While a little out of date, I do like it. (I found an old copy.)

Answer (score 3):

I know you are asking for books, but for up-to-date basic overview of how some methods work - I would try websites or YouTube instead of textbooks...

One good website is [BiteSizeBio](https://bitesizebio.com/webinars/). They have their own section for 'how to articles' and educational webinars. Otherwise I would also try YouTube. If you search in YouTube for basic techniques like 'how does the ELISA method work?' or 'principles behind SDS-PAGE' then you will find a lot of instructional movies. There is also the '[the protein man's blog](https://info.gbiosciences.com/blog)' for purification of proteins, some analysis but also some DNA things.

Comment: An additional recommendation would be https://www.jove.com , the journal for visualized experiments. Explains different experiments and methods through videos.

Answer (score 3):

Some protocols are not going out of style anytime soon, such as:

Frederick M. Ausubel, Roger Brent, Robert E. Kingston, David D. Moore, J. G. Seidman, John A. Smith, Kevin Struhl (2002) *Short Protocols in Molecular Biology*. Wiley, 1512pp. Check the Appendix sections for buffer formulations, etc. My copy is torn into pieces due to heavy use.

If you need the up-to-date form, then I recommend the subscription to Wiley's [Current Protocols in Molecular Biology](https://currentprotocols.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/journal/19343647).